# Javascript/JSON error: not well formed

Tags: javascript, json

I am testing putting a text editor on my page and storing it as part of a JSON object.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript">      </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
        <script src="/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="formSubmit.js">
            <textarea name ="editor"></textarea>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var text = $("editor").val();
    var name = "project name";
    var id = 5;
    var item = new item(name, text, id);
    var itemArray = localStorage.items;
    if (itemArray == undefined) {
        itemArray = [];
    } else {
        itemArray = JSON.parse(itemArray);
    }
    itemArray.push(item);
    localStorage.items = JSON.stringify(itemArray);
});
```

I want to be able to store `item` in a JSON object. When I run this I receive a "not-well formed" error at line 1 of the Javascript. It's a very simple program I'm running and can't seem to pinpoint what is causing the error. Is the JSON done incorrectly or are scripts in my HTML header causing issues?

Comment: You must use plain objects in your array, not Item instances.

Comment: what is the localstorage? alert your json data and see if you are getting the correct o/p

Answer (score 0):

$("editor") is looking for an html tag called 'editor'. you probably want to attach an id attribute to your  and do $('#editor')